# Correlate two variables per year and plot

Tags: r, regression

I am using the Lahman library to get data for baseball results, and in the code below, I calculated the OPS. But now I need help with calculating for every year the correlation between runs per game (R/G) and OPS and plotting these correlations as a function of year. Could you please help?

```
library (Lahman)
Teams %>% filter(yearID == 2002) %>%
  mutate(pa = AB + BB, BBPA=BB/pa, Singles = (H-X2B-X3B-HR)/G, Doubles=X2B/G, 
         Triples=X3B/G, HRAB=HR/AB) %>%
  mutate(OPS=BBPA+Singles+2*Doubles+3*Triples+4*HRAB) %>% select(OPS,R)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is correct, used `group_by()` and `summarise()` with `cor()`

```
df <- Teams %>% 
            mutate(pa = AB + BB, BBPA=BB/pa, Singles = (H-X2B-X3B-HR)/G, Doubles=X2B/G, 
                   Triples=X3B/G, HRAB=HR/AB) %>%
            mutate(OPS=BBPA+Singles+2*Doubles+3*Triples+4*HRAB) %>%
            select(yearID, OPS, R) 
    
    
    
    df %>%  group_by(yearID) %>%
    summarise(cor = cor(OPS, R)) %>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_line(aes(x = yearID, y = cor), color = "blue", size = 1.5)+
    labs(x = "Year", y = "Correlation between OPS vs R")+
    theme_classic()
```

[image: Graph output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do with just base R.

```
data(Teams, package='Lahman')

id <- unique(Teams$yearID)  ## used for x-axis

Teams |>
  within({
    pa <- AB + BB
    BBPA <- BB/pa
    Singles <- (H - X2B - X3B - HR)/G
    Doubles <- X2B/G
    Triples <- X3B/G
    HRAB <- HR/AB
    OPS <- BBPA + Singles + 2*Doubles + 3*Triples + 4*HRAB
  }) |>
  by(Teams$yearID, \(x) with(x, cor(OPS, R))) |>
  plot(type='l', xlab='year', ylab='r', xaxt='n', main='R/G and OPS over time', col=4) +
  axis(1, at=seq_along(id)[id %% 10 == 0], labels=id[id %% 10 == 0])
```

[image]